# How to run a macro defined in PERSONAL.XLSB for any opened workbook sheet when I change the cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I want to run the macro 'HighlightMisspelledCells' defined in the module node of Personal.xlsb on cell change of any workbook sheet.

I know that if I insert the following code on the sheet node in VBA Editor then this will call the macro defined in Personal.xlsb, but then for this, I have to insert this code every time for every new sheet, so is there any other way by which I simply add few lines in the PERSONAL.XLSB macro which runs on cell change of **any** opened sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.Run "Personal.xlsb!HighlightMisspelledCells"
End Sub
```

Note : There is also another problem (not specific to the question) is, when I save the above code then get an error message box "The Following feature cannot be saved in macro-free workbook" but still code works if I click on 'Yes' to save. But when I opened the same workbook next time then this 'Sheet specific' VBA code disappears.

PERSONAL.XLSB

```
Sub HighlightMisspelledCells()
    Dim cl As Range
        For Each cl In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            If Not Application.CheckSpelling(word:=cl.Text) Then
                cl.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Note : I am using MS Excel 2016 on Windows PC

I have already tried searching on the internet but have not been able to find a solution to my specific problem.

Comment: Just run the macro: `Developer -> Macros -> Personal.xlsb!HighlightMisspelledCells`

Comment: To achieve what you are asking for you could use Application Events [as described here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx)

Comment: That said, this is a really bad idea.  Spell checking every cell in the entire used range every time any cell changes will slow Excel to a crawl.  At most just check the cell(s) that changed

Comment: Is this the same question from same person in this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74928379/trigger-a-vba-macro-on-any-opened-workbook-and-sheets-with-following-code/74931566#74931566

Comment: You wrote : _But when I opened the same workbook next time then this 'Sheet specific' VBA code disappears_. Because you saved it as .xlsx (macro-free workbook). To have a code in a workbook, you have to save it as .xlsm. Please have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74928379/trigger-a-vba-macro-on-any-opened-workbook-and-sheets-with-following-code/74931566#74931566 if you're not the same person who ask a similar question.